# Cannot bind event to a dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-on

I'm trying to make a draggable div. I wrote some code to intercept the events with this html:

```
<div class="draggable">
    <iframe  id="frame" src="http://www.wikipedia.org"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's the js:

```
$(".draggable").bind("mousedown", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    $(".draggable").bind("mousemove",function(e){
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;
      $("#draggable").css({top: y, left: x});
    });
});
$(".draggable").bind("mouseup", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".draggable").unbind("mousemove");
});
$(".draggable").bind("touchstart touchmove", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var orig = e.originalEvent;
  var x = orig.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  var y = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY;
  // Move a div with id "rect"
   $(".draggable").css({top: y, left: x});
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xbv3opd7/34/

The issue is that the element does not seem to intercept the events. The code works if I bind the event to the document: http://jsfiddle.net/xbv3opd7/35/

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, question edited

Comment: The issue has to do with the tool you're using. You've selected  `No wrap - in head` from the menu on the left, which puts your code up at the top of the page.

Comment: It's actually somewhat baffling that you know how to write all that, but not that jQuery uses `document.ready` to make sure the DOM is ready ?

Answer (score -1):

Yea, because you'll first need to add jQuery-UI to your page.

You can download it here: http://jqueryui.com/download/

Then you need to make it [`.draggable()`](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), by doing this:

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

Let me know how that works for you.